# Будут ли загружаться данные из SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

Мы имеем **ActivityOne** и **ActivityTwo** .
В ActivityOne инциализируем `SharedPreferences sPref;` далее метод сохранения данных:

```
void saveText() {
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor ed = sPref.edit();
ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, etText.getText().toString());
ed.commit();
Toast.makeText(this, "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Вопрос, смогу ли я загрузить полученное значение в **ActivityTwo** следующим кодом:

инциализируем `SharedPreferences sPref;` далее метод загрузки данных:

```
void loadText() {
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
etText.setText(savedText);
Toast.makeText(this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Да, будут........

Comment: @ЮрийСПб болбшое спасибо за ответ. сейчас просто нет  времени это проверить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет не сможете! Используйте метод

```
getPreferences("NAME_FILE_FOR_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Указанный вами метод сохраняет преференсы в файл, который по умолчанию называется как и activity. В разных activity создаются разные файлы.

Comment: Простите, а `NAME_FILE_FOR_PREFERENCE`  я так понял это имя файла сохраненных настроек. Этот файл при сохранении данных создается сам? и как его вызвать на другом активити что бы вывести сохраненное значение? можете дать пример сохранения и вывода данных основываясь на моем коде. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: это просто строковая константа
    public final static String FILE_NAME = "file_name"

Comment: спасибо. работает